# Linq unwanted list

Tags: c#, linq

The following code produces two items. The first item contains a list of `Component` objects. The second item also contains a list of `Component` objects. In this example the second list should be empty, because the `Component` list does not have a `DishID=10`. How can I fix this problem?

In other words `result[1].components.Count` should be 0.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Component> Component = new List<Component>();
            List<Dish> Dish = new List<Dish>();
            Dish.Add(new Dish { DishID = 9, CategoryID = 6, DishName = "Pork" });
            Dish.Add(new Dish { DishID = 10, CategoryID = 6, DishName = "Beef" });
            Component.Add(new Component { ComponentID = 1, DishID = 9, AmountID = "1", NameID = "1" });

            List<Item> result = (from dishes in Dish
                                 join components in Component on dishes.DishID equals components.DishID
                                     into item
                                 from p in item.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new { CategoryID = dishes.CategoryID, DishID = dishes.DishID, ComponentID = p != null ? p.ComponentID : default(int), DishName = dishes.DishName, AmountID = p != null ? p.AmountID : null, NameID = p != null ? p.NameID : null }).ToList().GroupBy(key => key.DishID)
                                   .Select(g => new Item()
                                   {
                                       DishID = g.Key,
                                       components = g.Select(t => new Component { AmountID = t.AmountID, ComponentID = t.ComponentID, DishID = t.DishID, NameID = t.NameID }).ToList()
                                   })
                                       .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int DishID { get; set; }

        public List<Component> components { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Component
    {
        public int ComponentID { get; set; }
        public int DishID { get; set; }
        public string AmountID { get; set; }
        public string NameID { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Dish
    {
        public int DishID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string DishName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ComponentId is empty (in this case `0`), there is no match, so filter the empty `Component` objects when creating the result list items, in this case using `.Where (x => x.ComponentID > 0)` before the last select statement:

```
        List<Item> result = (from dishes in Dish
                             join components in Component on dishes.DishID equals components.DishID into item
                             from p in item.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new 
                                { 
                                    CategoryID = dishes.CategoryID, 
                                    DishID = dishes.DishID, 
                                    ComponentID = p != null ? p.ComponentID : default(int), 
                                    DishName = dishes.DishName,
                                    AmountID = p != null ? p.AmountID : null, 
                                    NameID = p != null ? p.NameID : null 
                                })
                               .ToList()
                               .GroupBy(key => key.DishID)
                               .Select(g => new Item()
                               {
                                   DishID = g.Key,
                                   components = g
                                                .Where (x => x.ComponentID > 0)
                                                .Select(t => new Component 
                                                                { 
                                                                    AmountID = t.AmountID, 
                                                                    ComponentID = t.ComponentID, 
                                                                    DishID = t.DishID,
                                                                    NameID = t.NameID 
                                                                })
                                                  .ToList()
                               })
                               .ToList();
```

Now the result contains two items, the first has `DishId=9` and the second list (for `DishId=10`) is empty.

If I understand you requirement correctly, I think the code could be simplified:

- iterate over each Dish item
- select items from the component list for the currently selected DishId: if there is no match, the list will be empty

The code looks like this:

```
        List<Item> result1 = new List<Item>();
        Dish.ForEach(dish =>
        {
            var item = new Item
            {
                DishID = dish.DishID,
                components = Component.Where (c => c.DishID == dish.DishID).ToList()
            };
            result1.Add(item);
        });
```

The output is the same as from your code.

---

Since you are making a [`LEFT JOIN` using LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) (with the `from p in item.DefaultIfEmpty()`), I assume you also want to exclude the empty items from the result. This can be done by adding a `where` condition (`where ((p != null) && (p.ComponentID > 0))`) to the first query:

```
       List<Item> result = (from dishes in Dish
                             join components in Component on dishes.DishID equals components.DishID into item
                             from p in item.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where ((p != null) && (p.ComponentID > 0))
                             select new 
                                { 
                                    CategoryID = dishes.CategoryID, 
                                    DishID = dishes.DishID, 
                                    ComponentID = p != null ? p.ComponentID : default(int), 
                                    DishName = dishes.DishName,
                                    AmountID = p != null ? p.AmountID : null, 
                                    NameID = p != null ? p.NameID : null 
                                })
                               .ToList()
                               .GroupBy(key => key.DishID)
                               .Select(g => new Item()
                               {
                                   DishID = g.Key,
                                   components = g.Select(t => new Component 
                                                                { 
                                                                    AmountID = t.AmountID, 
                                                                    ComponentID = t.ComponentID, 
                                                                    DishID = t.DishID,
                                                                    NameID = t.NameID 
                                                                })
                                                  .ToList()
                               })
                               .ToList();
```

The result contains, as expected, only the `Component` item for `DishId=9`.

Comment: I probably confused you. But result should contain two itens DishID=9(contain list components with 1 item), DishID=10(contain list components witn 0 items).

Comment: I modified the code in my answer to match this condition.

Comment: I have enhanced my answer with an alternative code solution.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't understand why you use all that left joins, group by and intermediate projection (select) while you can achieve the desired result with a simple [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) like this:

```
var result = (
    from d in Dish
    join c in Component on d.DishID equals c.DishID into items
    select new Item { DishID = d.DishID, components = items.ToList() }
    ).ToList();
```